# Find missing documents in MongoDB using aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, metabase

I am trying to find the missing documents in MongoDB. Scenario is like this: I have a collection where the documents have a hour-stamp field. I want to find which hours are missing given the time range.

Since I am writing this question on Metabase, I am limited to use only one aggregation pipeline, meaning I can't use `$out` to make temperate collection and do `$lookup` for join.

I can only fill in the code of `db.collection.aggregate(my code)`

Any idea how can I achieve this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Was able to achieve this so just sharing my solution.

Idea:

1. Generate an array for the hours needed to be checked. Notice I use
   hour-diff from current hour, so I can dynamically check if (-9
   hours) is missing. Reason for doing this is that I cannot find a way
   to programmatically generate this array using absolute hour-stamp
   (2022-07-11 10:00:00).
2. Calculate the hour-diff from current of the data's hour-stamp.
3. Use `$setDifference` to find the missing hours.
4. Calculate the absolute hour-stamp from the hour-diff value to get the missing hours.

Works for my need, and hope this will help someone.

Code snippet (I use this for finding missing hours between -6 to -30 hours for each data_source) :

```
db.getCollection(<collection_name>).aggregate(
[
    { $project: {
        _id: 1,
        data_source: 1,
        available_date_time: { $toDate: "$available_date_time"},
        current_hour: { $dateFromString: { dateString: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H", date: ISODate() } }, format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H" } },
    }},
    { $project: {
        _id:1,
        data_source:1,
        available_date_time: 1,
        current_hour: 1,
        current_hour_minus_6hr: { $subtract: [ "$current_hour", { $multiply: [6, 60, 60, 1000] }] },
        current_hour_minus_30hr: { $subtract: [ "$current_hour", { $multiply: [30, 60, 60, 1000] }] },
    }},
    { $project: {
        _id:1,
        data_source:1,
        available_date_time: 1,
        current_hour: 1,
        past_6hr_comp: { $subtract: [ { $toDate: "$available_date_time"}, "$current_hour_minus_6hr" ] },
        past_30hr_comp: { $subtract: [ { $toDate: "$available_date_time"}, "$current_hour_minus_30hr" ] },
    }},
    { $match: {
        $and: [
            { past_30hr_comp: { $gte: 0 } },
            { past_6hr_comp: { $lte: 0} }
        ]
    }},
    { $project: {
        _id: 1,
        data_source:1,
        available_date_time: 1,
        current_hour: 1,
        hour_diff_from_current: { $divide: [ {$subtract: [ "$current_hour", "$available_date_time" ] }, 3600000 ] }
    }},
    { $group: {
        _id: { data_source: "$data_source" },
        count: { $sum: 1 },
        available_hour_diff_set: { $addToSet: "$hour_diff_from_current" },
        current_hour: { $first: "$current_hour" }
    }},
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        data_source: "$_id.data_source",
        available_hour_count: "$count",
        available_hour_diff_set: "$available_hour_diff_set",
        required_hour_diff_set: [30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6],
        current_hour: "$current_hour"
    }},
    { $project: {
        data_source: 1,
        available_hour_count: 1,
        unavailable_hour_diff_set: { $setDifference: [ "$required_hour_diff_set", "$available_hour_diff_set" ] },
        current_hour:1
    }},
    { $unwind: "$unavailable_hour_diff_set" },
    { $project: {
        data_source: 1,
        available_hour_count: 1,
        current_hour: 1,
        unavailable_hour_diff: "$unavailable_hour_diff_set",
    }},
    { $project: {
        data_source: 1,
        available_hour_count: 1,
        current_hour: 1,
        unavailable_hour_diff: "$unavailable_hour_diff",
        missing_hour: { $subtract: [ "$current_hour", { $multiply: [ "$unavailable_hour_diff", 60, 60, 1000 ] } ] }
    }}
]
```